# protocols to transfer files

Tags: java, io, protocols, network-protocols

How do you decide which protocol you've to use to transfer/move/copy files across servers?
I'm writing a service to copy files from a Windows server file system to a oracle-based database.

Answer (score 1):

How about the [File Transfer Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) for transferring files.

Since Oracle doesn't store files, I suspect you need more than just transferring files.  I suspect you will need to use JDBC in any case.

Comment: Thx Peter, yes, I'm transferring JPGs for the most part, and saving it as a clob... my q is,  how do you decide its FTP, and not SSH that you need to use?

Comment: CLOB is for text, I would use BLOB for binary and you can perform the update via JDBC, so you don't need FTP or SSH.  You can use SSH if a) this is the only way to do the transfer or b) you need secure transfers. If you need to have secure transfers, you can use SCP or SFTP.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it's clear what you are building and why is it it a java question?

Do you need to implement a custom protocol in Java to transfer files for a web service you are building? Or can you use an off the shelf product and a bunch of shell scripts to take care of the file transfer?

If it's a custom thing you need to build in Java (the question is tagged with java) then more questions:

Is it a web app that provides end-users with GUI allowing them to submit files?
 - you need to take care of file transfer using http post. Apache httpclient library can help you there.

1. Is it a SOAP Web Service that saves incoming data into oracle?
     - again then SOAP implementations provide answer to that.
2. Is it a command-line tool running on Windows machine that talk to an Oracle database ?
     -then protocol is irrelevant, as you can just read the files using file.io libs and use jdbc to save them into oracle.
3. Is it a custom server with a yet-to-be built protocol and subsequently a custom client that will use that protocol? 
     - then I would use binary over https for my implementation of the custom server/service.

4.If you are doing everything using COTS, FTP is simple and fast, but it's not secure and it's not reliable. SFTP will almost always going to be better. 
http://geekswithblogs.net/bvamsi/archive/2006/03/23/73147.aspx

5.If your question is really about how to save files into Oracle database using jdbc, then you need to find a way to stream them (or you will run out of memory).

E.g. this may be helpful http://www.coderanch.com/t/415625/JDBC/databases/save-files-oracle-database-java